# Design Pattern for selectively exposing methods through SOAP and REST endpoints in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I have a WCF web service that defines IInterface interface. This interface declares two methods: Method1 and Method 2. I want to expose both of these methods through a SOAP endpoint, but want only Method2 exposed through REST endpoint.

Example declarations:

```
[ServiceContract]
public Interface IInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Method1();
    [OperationContract]
    void Method2();
}

public class MyService : IInterface
{
    public void Method1(){...}
    public void Method2(){...}
}
```

So far I have tried creating two additional interfaces: `IInterfaceSOAP` and `IInterfaceREST`, both inherited from `IInterface`. Removed `Method2()` declaration from `IInterface` and added it to `IInterfaceSOAP` and created two separate classes `MyServiceSOAP : IInterfaceSOAP` and `MyServiceREST : IInterfaceREST`. Then defined two separate endpoints for each derived class.

But when i test the service using `WcfTestClient`, the soap service only lists `Method1()` (the one that's defined in the base `IInterface`).

Is the above pattern an accepted solution for selectively exposing methods through two separate endpoints? Or is there some other approach that I have missed?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please note the above interface is extremely simplified version of what i'm trying to do. There are a lot more methods in the production version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... Due to huge number of methods i missed Method2. Since it was defined in a derived Interface, all methods in the base Interface came before this one and i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems a little smelly in that you have deployment concerns leaking into your service contracts and implementation. Given that REST does not expose metadata anyway I don't see a lot of benefit in the different interfaces.

I would have thought a behavior or ServiceAuthorizationManager, which examined the message version and disallowed access for REST requests would be a cleaner solution. That way you could have a single service implementation for a single contract and push protocol issues back to where they belong: deployment and configuration.

Comment: I do have endpoints and behaviors defined in web.config. All i'm trying to achieve is code reuse for both SOAP and REST endpoints, but selectively disallowing some of the methods in REST.

Comment: @Dimitri I can't quite get my head around how you are achieving code reuse with the differentiated interfaces since you say have two implementations - one for each differentiated interface. I'm suggesting that the limitations you're imposing on the REST interface migth simply be a deployment concern and therefore should be reflected there, rather than in the contract/implementation.

Comment: I have Base interface that has most of my methods that i want to use in both REST and SOAP. Then i derive two interfaces for each of the above types of service. SOAP one has additional methods that i want to be exposed, but the REST one doesn't. Now when i derive classes from both of those interfaces the implementation is only present in the class that is derived from SOAP interface (with all methods implemented), but the class that was derived from REST Interface only calls needed methods from SOAP class.